# Two steps build when your project contains XAML files, Visual Studio vs MSBuild

Tags: wpf, msbuild, visual-studio-2015, msbuild-task, msbuildcommunitytasks

There is project with output type as class library, which contains WPF controls. AssemblyInfo.cs should be generated before compile, and for that purpose there is next target (using MSBuild.Community.Tasks) which I imported at the end of `.csproj` file:

```
<Target Name="BeforeCompile">
    <AssemblyInfo CodeLanguage="CS"
        OutputFile="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs"
        AssemblyCompany="..."
        AssemblyCopyright="..."
        ComVisible="false"
        AssemblyVersion="..."
        AssemblyFileVersion="..."  />
</Target>
```

Before build file AssemblyInfo.cs does not exist.

And the problem is next: when building project from Visual Studio (2015) everything if fine, file is being created, but when I use MSBuild next error shows:

```
CSC : error CS2001:
Source file '...\Controls.Wpf\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs' could not be found.
[...\Controls.Wpf\en2zf2n0.tmp_proj]
```

**My hot fix**: is to name above target differently (which generates AssemblyInfo), let's say 'GenerateAssemblyInfo', and call it in project file this way, before all the build actions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="GenerateAssemblyInfo;Build" xmlns="...">
```

My guess is that happens because when there is `xaml` files - they need to be compiled into `baml` (that is why error is in **en2zf2n0.tmp_proj**, see above), and only after that 'real' build takes place. `BeforeCompile` happens somewhere between these two steps, and AssemblyInfo is needed before fist step, but there is no such.

**Question:** What is the difference between building with Visual Studio and MSBuild this **this** case, and is there any *proper* (*more proper*) way to solve this?